# MySQL - Indexes deleted, reduced column size but table size increases

Tags: mysql, innodb, index

Here is the original table definition which contains 107547934 (~107.5M) rows

```
    CREATE TABLE `twitter_tweets` (
      `id_str` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `id_user` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Twitter id of the user',
      `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `in_reply_to_user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Twitter id of the user being replied to, if any',
      `text` varchar(1000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `retweet_count` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `geo` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `retweeted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether the tweet has been retweeted at all',
      `place` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `in_reply_to_status_id_str` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `in_reply_to_screen_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `tweet_source` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `query` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
      `iso_language_code` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_str`,`tweet_source`,`query`),
      KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
      KEY `id_str` (`id_str`),
      KEY `query` (`query`),
      KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

The disk space usage stats are

[image: twitter_tweets disk usage]

I changed the primary key to just `id_str`, dropped the key named `id_str`, dropped the column named `geo`. I also changed the the column `tweet_source` from  varchar(100) to tinyint.  However, I did add two float columns `coordinates_long` and `coordinates_lat`. The column `geo` which was dropped only contained null values. The two new columns added also only contain null values. 
Here is the defn of the changed table which contains 106766691 (~106.7M) rows:-

```
    CREATE TABLE `twitter_tweets_new` (
      `id_str` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `id_user` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Twitter id of the user',
      `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
      `in_reply_to_user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Twitter id of the user being replied to, if any',
      `text` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `retweet_count` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
      `coordinates_long` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `coordinates_lat` float DEFAULT NULL,
      `retweeted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Indicates whether the tweet has been retweeted at all',
      `place` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `in_reply_to_status_id_str` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `in_reply_to_screen_name` varchar(256) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `tweet_source` tinyint(4) NOT NULL COMMENT '1=user_timeline, 2=search',
      `query` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'None',
      `iso_language_code` varchar(5) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id_str`),
      KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
      KEY `query` (`query`),
      KEY `created_at` (`created_at`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

The disk space usage stats are

[image: twitter_tweets_new disk usage]

When you compare the size of the 2 tables, the former (named `twitter_tweets` occupies less space than the latter `twitter_tweets_new`).

Although there was a net addition of one column, considering that the null values  don't take much space and also that I reduced the index size by a lot and also changed one of the columns to a smaller datatype and that the new table has lesser number of rows than the original one, the table size of the new table `twitter_tweets_new` should have been much lesser than that of `twitter_tweets`. 
Why could this be happening?

Answer (score 2):

Of course, the index size collapsed because you reduced the `PRIMARY KEY` to a single column and removed `KEY`id_str`(`id_str`),`. This definitely reduced all secondary indexes. That is excellent.

## What about the Removal of Columns ?

You removed `geo`, which were all `NULL`. There was no shrinkage for the data. Why ? Since all `geo` columns were `NULL`, ***it took no space at all in every row***. The mapping of offsets for all fields had `geo` pointing at nothing at all.

In the MySQL Documentation on [FIELD CONTENTS in InnoDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-field-contents.html), it has the following example table

```
CREATE TABLE T
    (FIELD1 VARCHAR(3), FIELD2 VARCHAR(3), FIELD3 VARCHAR(3))
    Type=InnoDB;
```

Note that both `FIELD1` and `FIELD3` are `VARCHAR` fields with `NULL` values.

From the Helpful Notes About `NULL` values at the [Bottom of that Page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/innodb-field-contents.html)

> For the third row, I inserted NULLs in FIELD2 and FIELD3. Therefore in
>   the Field Start Offsets the top bit is on for these fields (the values
>   are 94 hexadecimal, 94 hexadecimal, instead of 14 hexadecimal, 14
>   hexadecimal). And the row is shorter because the NULLs take no space.

Thus, removing a `VARCHAR` column where every value was `NULL` will not shrink the table.

## What did adding FLOAT columns actually do ?

Let's play a little math game. You said the new table has 106.7M rows.

- Each FLOAT column occupies 4 bytes
- You added 2 FLOATs, so that is 8 bytes
- The amount of space reserved for a FLOAT is still fixed at 4 bytes, even for a NULL FLOAT.
- That 853.6M bytes which is 814 MiB.

At first glance, you would think that Data should have increased from 20.8 GiB to 21.6 GiB. What should have been 4% increase, increasing by 814MB, grew to 37.3 GiB, which is a 79.3% increase in Data.

## Why Did the Data Grow So Much ?

Please be aware that there is an object in the table called [gen_clust_index, a.k.a. the table's Clustered Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-index-types.html). This is the table's `PRIMARY KEY`. You may find this shocking, but the `PRIMARY KEY` does not reside in the table's index pages. It resides in the table's Data Pages.

Question: What is the size of a page in InnoDB ? [Answer: 16KB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size).

What is inside the 16KB of a Data Page ?

- Data for one or more rows
- BTREE information for the `PRIMARY KEY`
- Leaf Nodes that point to a row are in the same page

Remember you added two FLOATs ? This makes each row 8 bytes bigger. Each row will expand in the 16KB of the Data Page, leaving less room for BTREE information. What must InnoDB do to maintain the `PRIMARY KEY` ? Create additional Data pages to accommodate wider rows along with the associated BTREE information.

Since the PRIMARY KEY is a BTREE, you should expect O(n log n) growth in BTREE nodes, along with an overflow of InnoDB Data pages.

Without doing any further math, I will show you how this is the case.

MyISAM has data and indexes stored separately.

Run the following

```
CREATE TABLE twitter_tweets_myisam LIKE twitter_tweets_new;
ALTER TABLE twitter_tweets_myisam ENGINE=MyISAM;
ALTER TABLE twitter_tweets_myisam DISABLE KEYS;
INSERT INTO twitter_tweets_myisam SELECT * FROM twitter_tweets_new;
ALTER TABLE twitter_tweets_myisam ENABLE KEYS;
```

I can assure you that the `.MYD` file of `twitter_tweets_myisam` will not be 37.3 GiB

## [Q.E.D.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.)

Comment: Thanks. I created a myisam table as you suggested and its size is indeed 16.2GiB(data)+4.2GiB(index). However, theres one more thing to account for- In twitter_tweets_new, I had also changed the column tweet_source from varchar to tinyint. I checked the values for that column in twitter_tweets- there are no non-NULL values and all of them are 13 chars long which considering utf8_unicode_ci should occupy 39 bytes for each entry but only 1 byte in twitter_tweets_new. So,even with the 2 float columns we should have 30 bytes less in each row- isn't it? Or does it not work that way?